# Export a union type alias in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to export something like this:

```
export TypeA | TypeB as TypeAB;
```

and declare a variable of `TypeAB` that can be either of `TypeA` or `TypeB`:

```
import {TypeAB} from './typeab';
var ab: TypeAB;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yeah, just needs the correct syntax for a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
export type TypeAB = TypeA | TypeB;
```